# Combine the type of 2 objects and warn when accessing a prop that exists only in one of them

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a simple translation feature in React with TypeScript. I'm storing all strings in plain objects and exposing the translation object matching the language of the user.

```
const en = {
  hi: 'hi'
  bye: 'bye',
}

const it = {
  hi: 'ciao'
}

type Translations = typeof en & typeof it;
```

In code it would be used like this, with autocomplete, where `translations` is either object depending on the language of the user:

```
<h1>{translations.bye}</h1>
```

The problem is that the 2 translation objects might get out of sync, where one would contain a string and the other wouldn't, just like in the case above. However TypeScript wouldn't know about this because of the intersection type and because the language is set at runtime.

How can I type this so TypeScript warns me about using a property that doesn't exist in all the objects?

Comment: `type Translations = typeof en | typeof it;`? `translations` is going to be *one* of those types, not all of them. Better yet, define the `Translations` type **first** so that the compiler can tell you that `it` is missing a translation for `bye`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then I'd have to treat one of the languages as the base type. But what if then `en` is behind `it`? I could define it this way and make it clear to all devs that an English string is needed first, but it would be awesome if it worked both ways.

Comment: No you wouldn't. All of the languages would implement a predefined type, e.g. `interface Translations { hi: string; bye string; }`.

Comment: I would prefer to not do that, just to keep it easy to maintain. It would also not work with "Go to definition". It would go to the interface and not the source of the string. The intersection type works great in this case, "Go to definition" would prompt me to select which definition/language to go to which makes it very easy to update translations.

Comment: Then use the union instead, but an intersection makes no sense here.

Comment: True. Do you know if there's a way to prettify the error message? With large objects it looks insane and you can't tell which language is missing the property.

Comment: Then you come back to a predefined type, which would tell you there was a missing translation in one of your language definitions *where you defined it*. I really don't understand your objections in the comment above, it's unclear why you think that's less *"easy to maintain"*.

Comment: I meant it adds another place where you have to define a property, compared to just inferring it from the source.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator will create a record type containing all possible values from initial translation types. So in the result you get Cartesian product of both records, so your final type `Translations` contains all properties from all translations, and that is clearly not what you want. You can achieve the need really by using union `|`.

```
type Translations = typeof en | typeof it; // it will work like intersection
```

But what I propose here instead, is to create base language, pick one, or base type which will define minimum required words to be translated. Lets say:

```
const it = {
  hi: 'ciao'
}
const en = {
    hi: 'hi',
    bye: 'bye',
}

type MinimumTranslation = typeof it; // I picked it, but can be any othere, or special one
type Translation = Partial<typeof it & typeof en> & MinimumTranslation;

function someF (tr: Translation) {
    tr.hi // is here always
    tr.bye // is there as optional property
}
```

The solution is to create base minimum definition what every language object should provide, and also provide information that some languages have more, this is exactly `Translation` type, it says - I have multiplication of all possible language fields, but these fields are not guaranteed to be set (pay attention using Partial utility type), but there is required amount of fields which are always there (`& MinimumTranslation`).

---

Such base type can be just a type definition, no need to have representation:

```
type RequiredTranslation = 'hi' | 'dog' | 'cat'; // all minimum required words
type MinimumTranslation = Record<RequiredTranslation, string>
```

Full example with using `MinimumTranslation` type:

```
type RequiredTranslation = 'hi' // all required words for all translations
type MinimumTranslation = Record<RequiredTranslation, string>

// id function for proper type structure representation
const makeTranslation = <T extends MinimumTranslation>(a: T): T => {
    return a;
}

// using makeTranslation requires that argument has all required as minimum translations
const en = makeTranslation({
    hi: 'hi',
    bye: 'bye',
});

const it = makeTranslation({
  hi: 'hi',
})

type Translation = Partial<typeof it & typeof en> & MinimumTranslation;

function someF (tr: Translation) {
    tr.hi // is here always
    tr.bye // is there as optional property
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I think what I need is simply a union type, I don't know what I didn't think about it. My only problem with it is that I can't make it tell me the name of the type a property is missing from, instead of the type itself. It makes the error messages worthless. But at the same time I only need to support to languages and if I added one translation, but not the other, then as long as I get an error message I know what's missing.

Comment: "The `&` operator is not really the intersection for types".  I'm not sure why you say this.  Object types in TypeScript are extendible, not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So `const x = {a: "", b: 1}` is assignable both to `const a: {a: string} = x;` and `const b: {b: number} = x;`.  If you think of types as sets of possible values, then the set for `{a: string}` and the set for `{b: number}` *intersect*, and the intersection is `{a: string, b: number}`.  So `{a: string} & {b: number}` is `{a: string, b: number}`

Comment: Intersection from the set theory is a set which contains all values from type A and type B, so all values which exists in one and another. For example if you have a set (1,2,3) and (3,4) then intersection is 3. If we have a type C {c:string} and D {d: string} the intersection is none. There is nothing which is in one and another. So & creates here a multiplication as possible values are equal |C| * |D|. Maybe I see that completely wrong @jcalz but this really not looks like intersection.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_type ok need to rethink. Thanks @jcalz

Comment: From your own example, `const cd = {c: "", d: ""}; const c: C = cd; const d: D = cd;` works, right?  The value `cd` is both a `C` and a `D`. [Observe](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeUDGAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmUAvgNwBQokUAIgslACaY4EnnWoD2hONCyYoMUAETiANK0yTuVPgOBpMcRKhYUoAeh1ReAawCGIRf0FsGTTdr0GTIKFSA).  Please read about [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and how they differ from what TypeScript currently has (and how [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) obscure this)

Comment: @jcalz yes you are right. Still intersection looks here like a superset where the element is a product of both elements from original types. So all elements from type A and B are inside the intersection. In terms of structure the result is and A and B agree.

Comment: @jcalz look on that related to our discussion topic -  https://twitter.com/BartoszMilewski/status/1202374417759625216.

Comment: What do you mean by "element"?  Do you mean "property"?  If so, then yes, properties are related contravariantly to objects... so the properties of `A & B` are `keyof A | keyof B` while the properties of `A | B` are `keyof A & keyof B`.  Intersections of object types imply unions of their properties, and unions of object types imply intersections of their properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203990/discussion-between-maciej-sikora-and-jcalz).